# How to flatten an array of objects while looping in Jolt Transformation?

Tags: java, jolt

I am trying to use Jolt to transform my incoming message into a list of certain custom objects.

However, in case of nested values in incoming array, I am not able to get the desired output.

**Incoming message:**

```
[
  {
    "type": "Hourly",
    "employeeIdDetails": [
      {
        "id": "900",
        "idType": "HR_EMP"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "Salaried",
    "employeeIdDetails": [
      {
        "id": "436",
        "idType": "SAL_EMP"
      },
      {
        "id": "111",
        "idType": "SAL_EMP"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "Salaried",
    "employeeIdDetails": [
      {
        "id": "437",
        "idType": "SAL_EMP"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Jolt Spec**

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "type": {
          "Salaried": {
            "@2": {
              "employeeIdDetails": {
                "*": {
                  "idType": {
                    "SAL_EMP": {
                      "@2": {
                        "id": "test[&4].ids",
                        "idType": "test[&4].types"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Current Output:**

```
{
  "test" : [ {
    "ids" : [ "436", "437" ],
    "types" : [ "SAL_EMP", "SAL_EMP" ]
  }, {
    "ids" : "111",
    "types" : "SAL_EMP"
  } ]
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
{
  "test" : [ {
    "ids" : "436",
    "types" : "SAL_EMP"
  } ,
{
    "ids" : "111",
    "types" : "SAL_EMP"
  } ,
 {
    "ids" : "437",
    "types" : "SAL_EMP"
  } ]
}
```

The order does not really matter to me other than having all the objects.

The problem, I think, I have found out so far is using "&".
But, not sure how I can combine values into 1 object without that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that way suits you?

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "type": {
          "Salaried": {
            "@(2,employeeIdDetails)": {
              "*": {
                "idType": {
                  "SAL_EMP": {
                    "@2": "test[]"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "test": {
        "*": {
          "id": "test[&1].ids",
          "idType": "test[&1].types"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Analyzing this helped me: https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/test/resources/json/chainr/integration/wolfermann2.json